# is there a limit on length of key name on MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, key-value

Are there any character length limitations on MongoDB key? How about limitations on depth of keys.

For example `db.namespace.key_depth1.key_depth2.key_depth3`...
How many level of key can we have? Is there a limit on length of concatenated key string above? 
How about other key value database?

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB has a great page dedicated to [its limits and thresholds](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restriction-on-Collection-Names)

To put it shortly:

```
limit for the database name:
64 characters

limit for the database name + collection name (<database>.<collection>):
120 characters (including the dot separator)

(This is the closest answer to your question, since it limits the amount of keys)
nesting limit:
100
```

So since your question is regarding the length of a key, it varies. If you're able to fit in the 120 character limit for the database and collection name, then the only limitation is nesting. Mongo only supports `100` nested layers, meaning it only supports queries that are requesting a retrieval of a nested key that is no deeper than 100 layers. I don't think that the query itself is limited, but since the database doesn't support more than 100 levels, the query just wouldn't make sense.

So if your database name is really short, like `app`, then your collection name limit is 116 characters, so the query could look like this:

`db.<116 characters>.find({'1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.(and so on until).100': true})`

Other than that, there seems to be no fixed limit for a key length.

Answer (score 0):

I have run in to this limit but ended up getting around it by using deterministic hashing of the record to generate an ID less than the threshold.  You can browse the BSON tree with filters on querying if needed.  It's not really an ideal solution though...